# PHP Multiple actions in true clause in shorthand IF

Tags: php, conditional-operator, shorthand-if

Pretty sure there's a simple answer to this but difficult to search on because of the vague terms used.

I'm using shorthand if statements and want to do more than one action when it returns true, what does the syntax look like?

For example, logically thinking I tried something like:

```
<?php

$var = "whatever";

(isset($var) ? $var2=$var; $var3=$var : $error="fubar");

?>
```

Obviously this stops with unexpected ; but hopefully you get the idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

So sorry if this is a duplicate question, I swear I searched for it. :)

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I understand that whether or not shorthand is appropriate for this situation should be questioned. But still, can it be done, is the question.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. I think you just have to do if (...) { ... } else { ... }

Comment: `$var1 = $var2 = $var3 = (isset($var) ? $var : $error = 'foobar');`

Comment: When you start grouping ternaries together, your code just committed a WTF of unread-ability.

Comment: No its not, CodeAngry. It was the source of a bet and I won. :) But everyone here appreciates your optimism. kthx!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it's possible by using `&&` between each assignment:

```
(isset($var) ? ($var2=$var) && ($var3=$var) : $error="fubar");
```

In the above code, if `$var` is set, `$var2` and `$var3` will get the same value, otherwise the two variables will not be changed.

That said, it is not the most appropriate method. The ternary operator should be used for simple logic, when the logic starts to get complicated, ternary is most likely no longer the best option. Instead you should just use a simple if/else.

Comment: In this particular case you could even do: `isset($var) ? $var2 = $var3 = $var : $error = 'foobar';`

Comment: hum... if $var == false, the second part of the && operator will not execute, right ? otherwise, it works, but it hurts my eyes x_x.

Comment: -1 If `$var` is false, `&&` and the following will not execute. This is when you need to use `if...else`. Stop responding to weird questions and guide them to the right way of doing it, not what posters imagine.

Answer (score 1):

**For this specific instance, you can do this:**

In this specific instance you can use this:

```
$output = (isset($var)) ? $var2 = $var3 = $var : false;
```

Slightly better option for this specific test instance:

```
$error = (isset($var)) ? !(bool)($var2 = $var3 = $var) : true;
```

*This will set `$error` to `true` IF `$var` is not set, and to `false` if `$var` is set, so you could follow this up with an `if($error)` block.*

**However, ternary probably isn't the best way to approach this...**

For more complicated instances you'd need to use closures or, worse, predeclared functions:

```
$output = (isset($var)) ? setVars($var) : false;

function setVars($var) {
    $var2 = $var3 = $var;
}
```

At this point, you're probably better off with `if` or `switch` statements.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible, and shouldn't be possible. `(?:)` is not, and should not be taken as a `if`, because it doesn't works the same way, and is not designed for it.

The ternary operator exist as a way to return a value depending of a condition, not as a "quick" if.

If you are using it without needing the return value, then you probably are using it wrong.

In this specific case, you should be using and if-else statement. It would also help making your code more readable.

Comment: I understand your point, just slightly bummed it has to be 'that' simple. But I suppose the line between simple and complex has to be drawn somewhere...

Comment: The thing is the ternary has been created for a specific case of if-else : if(condition){value=X;}else{value=Y}. You can try to use for other things, but keep in mind that it basically reproduce this behavior, and thus is limited to the same kind of operations.